# Need to Add button and overlay on AVPlayerView for tvOS

Tags: swift, avplayer, tvos, apple-tv, avplayerview

Can we add button on `AVPlayerViewController` and show overlay over that or we need to customize the controls.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `View Controller Containment` to add `AVPlayerViewController`s view to your `UIViewController` then you can add anything you want over the `AVPlayerViewController`s view since it is just another view in the view hierarchy...

```
let avPlayerVC = AVPlayerViewController()
//configure the playerVC
addChildViewController(avPlayerVC)
avPlayerVC.view.frame = frame//or use autolayout to constran the view properly
view.addSubview(avPlayerVC.view)
avPlayerVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

//add controls over it -> I called it ControlsView
let controls = ControlsView()
view.addSubview(controls)
```

Comment: Cant we add customized subtitles to info view rather than going with above approach?